# How to differentiate between reflow and repaint in chrome developer tools?

Tags: frontend, repaint, reflow

How to differentiate between **repaint**

> A repaint occurs when changes are made to elements that affect
>   visibility but not the layout. For example, opacity, background-color,
>   visibility, and outline. Repaints are expensive because the browser
>   must check the visibility of all other nodes in the DOM — one or more
>   may have become visible beneath the changed element.

and **reflow**

> Reflows have a bigger impact. This refers to the re-calculation of
>   positions and dimensions of all elements, which leads to re-rendering
>   part or all of the document. Changing a single element can affect all
>   children, ancestors, and siblings.

using chrome developer tools(or other similar tools)?

In Chrome Performance tab i see only repaint.
[repaint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wnSG.png)